# Como redirecionar pra outra rota e passar variáveis no processo? Node + Express

Tags: node.js, express.js, redirect

Gostaria de redirecionar utilizando o res.redirect() para que a URL também seja alterada, mas não estou conseguindo enviar informações no processo, alguém conseguiria me dizer como fazer isso? Quero enviar junto a variável "func", que contém o id do funcionário selecionado, e na rota "editarFuncionario", renderizar a página com as informações do usuário que será alterado.

```
app.post('/funcionarios', function(req, res){
let botao = req.body.botao;
let func = req.body.id;

if (botao == "Editar"){
    res.redirect('/editarFuncionario');
}...

app.get('/editarFuncionario', function(req, res){
  let query = db.query("SELECT * FROM funcionarios WHERE id = ?", [func], function(err, results){
            if (err) throw err;
           res.render('editarFuncionario', {lista:results});
        })
  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

O `.redirect` usa-se para redirecionar a resposta, não o pedido (request). Tens de fazer isso chamando funções internas. Ou seja em vez da lógica de redirecionamento deves, dentro desse `if` ter a lógica da base de dados que tens na pergunta.

Podes fazer isso no mesmo ficheiro (como no exemplo em baixo) ou importando funções de outros ficheiros e chamá-las dentro do `if`.

Exemplo:

```js
app.post('/funcionarios', function(req, res) {
  let botao = req.body.botao;
  let func = req.body.id;

  if (botao == "Editar") {
    db.query("SELECT * FROM funcionarios WHERE id = ?", [func], function(err, results) {
      if (err) throw err;
      res.render('editarFuncionario', {
        lista: results
      });
    })
  } else {
    // outra query com outra resposta
  }
});
```

Comment: Então, eu tinha feito dessa maneira antes, mas a URL se mantém inalterada, e ao clicar no botão "enviar", para realizar a alteração dos dados do funcionário, o redirecionamento é feito para a URL responsável por listar os funcionários, já que o render não altera a URL. Teria como fazer de algum jeito que alterasse ela?

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema, bastava tirar a declaração "let" atrás da variável, assim consigo acessar ela em qualquer outra função, obrigado por ajudar!